# How to get Nested Dictionary Item in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I using Umbraco 7.4.3.

I created few dictionary items (rot item with few children items), like below:
HomePage
    Intro
    Body

When I try to get dictionary value for sub-item I getting empty string, however for root item I get correct result.

For example, 
this call works - returns value according to current language:

> @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("HomePage")

but this call doesn't work - returns empty string:

> @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("HomePage.Intro")

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the child dictionary item has the full key specified: "HomePage.Intro"

Your tree should look like this:

```
HomePage
- HomePage.Intro
```

An example of the dictionary tree I'm currently using:

[image]

Comment: Exactly. Dictionary items may be *organized* with folders inside Umbraco, but the keys have to be unique for you to reference them.